# Code libraries/applications in C#

Tags: c#, math, statistics, matrix

I am refreshing my memory on C# (first used it several years ago), and I want to look at some real world quality code (rather than the simplistic ones used in many books).

My preference would be mathematical/statistics libraries written in C# as I would like to see how Matrices and PDEs (partial differential equations etc) are implemented in C#.

Can anyone recommend a good quality online resource where I can view some 'industrial grade' preferably (Math/Stats) library/application written in C#?

Comment: Community Wiki, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Math .NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) may be will be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. looks very interesting/promising.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [WPF Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/).

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/SVN) (an open source, cross platform implementation of .net) is also open source.

Comment: +1: wow - thats very interesting (WPF 3D). I am already using mono ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Numerical Methods](http://numerical.codeplex.com/) and the related projects might be of interest.